# Logout function not clearing ParseUser currentUser after parse migration in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse SDK 1.13.1 for Android and I need to logout user on button click. it's working but when I call ParseUser.getCurrentUser() it's give me last logged in user instead of null.

For Parse Initialize i write below code :

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this).applicationId("PARSE_APPLICATIONID").clientKey("PARSE_CLIENT_KEY").server("PARSE_SERVER_URL").build());
```

For logout i write below code

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

and also tried

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();

ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this should be null but not
```

But, it seems that ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); after log out is not null.

How I can remove current user from cache?

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk. You can treat this cache as a session, and automatically assume the user is logged in.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
  // do stuff with the user
} else {
  // show the signup or login screen
}
```

You can clear the current user by logging them out.

```
ParseUser.logOut();
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this will now be null
```

Make sure that you have all your functions correctly set and that you not authenticating the user again etc.

If you have Automatic user creation enabled, logging out and then fetching the current user will produce a new anonymous user. This on by default in the starter projects so that you can start using users and ACLs immediately.

if `[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];` set in your `appDelegate,` current user will never return nill

Comment: Found a issue on the repo that suggest it could be a bug. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/539

Answer (score 0):

Please check below:

```
public static Task<Void> logOutInBackground()
```

or

```
public static void logOutInBackground(LogOutCallback callback)
```

method with ParseUser Like below:
`ParseUser.logOutInBackground();` or

```
ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback )
```

Hope it will work...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried ParseUser.logOutInBackground(new LogOutCallback) this it's gives ParseUser.getCurrentUser() is null.

But after second time fetch user detail like ParseUser.getCurrentUser() it's gives previous logged user.